# Replacing characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have created a simple program that i want to replace some chars with others in array of string.I have created an array of string that contains some words,i want to loop on each word and check on some chars if it contains,but when i tried to replace nothing happens
here is my code

```
            string x = "";
            x = "Script friends above about type=text/javascript>BBC.adverts.writeleaderboardtrue) all </script>friends,eating,khaled,khaled,khaled";
 char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t', ':', '$', '=', ';', '<', '>', '!', ';', ']', '[', '"',
                                    '/','=','-','?'};
 string[] words = x.Split(delimiterChars);
            for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
            {
                words[j] = words[j].ToLower();
            }
 for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < words[j].Length; j++)
                {

                    if (words[i][j]=='a'||words[i][j]=='e'||words[i][j]=='i'||words[i][j]=='o'||words[i][j]=='u'
                        ||words[i][j]=='h'||words[i][j]=='w'||words[i][j]=='y')
                    {
                        words[i].Replace(words[i][j],'0');
                    }
                    else if (words[i][j] == 'b' || words[i][j] == 'f' || words[i][j] == 'p' || words[i][j] == 'v')
                    {
                        words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '1');
                    }

                     else if (words[i][j] == 'c' || words[i][j] == 'g' || words[i][j] == 'j' || words[i][j] == 'k'
                    || words[i][j] == 'q' || words[i][j] == 's' || words[i][j] == 'x' || words[i][j] == 'z')
                {
                    char xx = words[i][j];
                    words[i].Replace(xx, '2');
                    Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
                }
                else if (words[i][j] == 'd' || words[i][j] == 't')
                {
                    words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '3');
                }
                else if (words[i][j] == 'l')
                {
                    words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '4');
                }
                else if (words[i][j] == 'm' || words[i][j] == 'n')
                {
                    words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '5');
                }
                else if (words[i][j] == 'r')
                {
                    words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '6');
                }



}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting that Strings are immutable.

`words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '1')` returns a new String instange with the replaced values.

You have to assign your reference back to the newly generated String object:

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '1');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.Replace` operation does not mutate the original string.  You have to set the result back to the source variable to apply the change.

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i][j], '0');
```

Note that replace applies to the whole string, so searching for every single `a`, `e`, etc. letter by letter and calling replace is redundant. You can just do this:

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace('a', '0');
words[i] = words[i].Replace('e', '0');
// etc..
```

or better yet, use a regular expression:

```
words[i] = Regex.Replace(words[i], "[aeiouhwy]", "0");
words[i] = Regex.Replace(words[i], "[bfvp]", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make the same thing in a match more compact and efficient way. I.e, this:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < words[j].Length; j++)
            {

                if (words[i][j]=='a'||words[i][j]=='e'||words[i][j]=='i'||words[i][j]=='o'||words[i][j]=='u'
                    ||words[i][j]=='h'||words[i][j]=='w'||words[i][j]=='y')
                {
                    words[i].Replace(words[i][j],'0');
                }
```

can be replaced with a simple Regex replace like this:

```
  Regex re0 = new Regex("[aeiouhwy]"); // match any of this chras
  string changedWord = re0.Replace(word,"0");
```

You can even chain calls to `Replace`method like this:

```
  Regex re0 = new Regex("[aeiouhwy]"); // match any of this chras
  Regex re1 = new Regex("[bfpv]");
  string changedWord = re0.Replace(word,"0");
  changedWord = re1.Replace(changedWord,"1")
```

and so on. Easier to write and understand, and more efficient.